# Solving a maximize problem in r using lpSolve with for loop?

Tags: r

I'm new to r and am struggling to solve the following maximize problem.

Consider the following dataframe:

`cars week1 week2 week3 week4 week5 week6 week7 week8 week9 week10 breakevenCoverage
audi   20    20    21    21    20    19    22    22    22    22     0.71
tesla  12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12     0.74
bmw    12    12    12    12    12    13    13    13    13    13     0.73
toyota  1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0.71
honda   6     6     7     7     7     7     7     8     8     8     0.71`

Let's say this represents the number of cars a car rental company has available for rent over a 10 week period.  We need to cover the cars with insurance but insurance can only be purchased for a 10 week block (i.e. the number of cars covered can't vary week to week). Based on how many cars we choose to cover with insurance, we can determine the **aggregate** coverage of the car fleet fairly easily.  For example, if we cover 18 audis for a 10 week period, the aggregate coverage of the fleet would be 18 x 10 / (20+20+21+21+20+19+22+22+22+22) = 86.1%.

Now consider the **incremental** coverage of insuring an additional car.  For example, if we cover a 19th audi, it is covering a car for all 10 weeks (since each week there is at least 19 cars) so the incremental coverage is 100%.  If I cover a 20th audi, the insurance is covering a car for 9 of the 10 weeks (all except week6), so the incremental coverage is 90%.  If I cover a 21st audi, the insurance is covering a car for 6 of the 10 weeks (since in weeks 1,2,5,6 there are < 21 cars for rent), so the incremental coverage is 60%.

For each car, I'm trying to determine the maximum number of cars to insure such that the **incremental** coverage of adding a car to the policy is >= to the given breakeven coverage for that car.

I think about the problem this way:

Objective: Maximize `numCarsToInsure`, where

Constraints: `incrCoverage >= breakevenCoverage`, where `incrCoverage` is

`for i = 1 to 10
   if week[i] >= numCarsToInsure then
      Covered = Covered + 1
incrCoverage = Covered / 10`

(the above loop should be evaluated for each value of numCarsToInsure as part of the solve)

For audi, numCarsToInsure should be 20 where the incrCoverage is 90%.  If NumCarsToInsure is 21, the incrCoverage drops to 60% which is < breakevenCoverage of 71%.  For tesla, numCarsToInsure should be 12 where the incrCoverage is 100%.  If numCarsToInsure is 13, the incrCoverage drops to 0% which is < breakevenCoverage of 74%.  And so forth.

Is lpSolve the right approach?  If so, how do I model the for loop with the lp() function?

Another approach would be to start with numCarsToInsure = 0, solve for incrCoverage, compare to breakevenCoverage, and then keep incrementing numCarsToInsure and resolving until incrCoverage drops below the breakevenCoverage.  But I'm hoping r has some sort of elegant solve function that does that vs. hand crafting.

If I can figure out how to solve for a given observation, I can figure out the entire dataframe, but code that solves for the entire dataframe would be super helpful.

Thank you!!

Comment: Welcome. Can you re-explain what incremental utility is without the for loop code? This is kind of confusing. What is x? There is no objective function equation

Comment: @EvanFriedland I edited the question so it's specific vs. generic and added some additional explanation.  Please let me know if this helps.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for flushing out your question. I don't think you need any form of optimization to perform this maximization. Certainly not lpSolve or optim. You are only insuring an additional car (whole number, no fractions of a car) until you equal or exceed breakeven coverage. For this, a `while` loop will suffice:

```
# reproducible dataset - best practice is to use dput(yourData) to generate this
dat <- data.frame(
  cars = structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("audi", "bmw", "honda", 
                                                     "tesla", "toyota"), class = "factor"),
  week1 = c(20L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 6L),
  week2 = c(20L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 6L),
  week3 = c(21L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 7L),
  week4 = c(21L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 7L),
  week5 = c(20L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 7L),
  week6 = c(19L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 7L),
  week7 = c(22L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 7L),
  week8 = c(22L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 8L),
  week9 = c(22L, 12L, 13L, 0L, 8L),
  week10 = c(22L, 12L, 13L, 0L, 8L),
  breakevenCoverage = c(0.71, 0.74, 0.73, 0.71, 0.71),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# I like to initialize all my empty objects 
dat[,"covered"] <- 0 # initialize the column we will fill with results
dat[,"coveredPercent"] <- 0
coveredPercent <- 0

for(i in 1:nrow(rawdat)){ # for each car
  covered = 0 # start at zero
  coveredPercent = 0
  while(coveredPercent < rawdat[i, "breakevenCoverage"]){
    covered <- covered + 1 
    coveredPercent <- covered*10/sum(dat[i, 2:11])
  }
  dat[i, "covered"] <- covered
  dat[i, "coveredPercent"] <- coveredPercent
}
dat
```

Which shows the result:

```
    #cars week1 week2 week3 week4 week5 week6 week7 week8 week9 week10 breakevenCoverage covered coveredPercent
#1   audi    20    20    21    21    20    19    22    22    22     22              0.71      15      0.7177033
#2  tesla    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12     12              0.74       9      0.7500000
#3    bmw    12    12    12    12    12    13    13    13    13     13              0.73      10      0.8000000
#4 toyota     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0      0              0.71       1      1.2500000
#5  honda     6     6     7     7     7     7     7     8     8      8              0.71       6      0.8450704
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Did this answer your question?